# Python 3: Trying to change a dictionary to a string and write to file, but it still won't write to file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take text files, count the word usage of each word as key-value pairs in dictionaries, and write each dictionary to their own file. Then, I want to add all of the dictionaries together into one master dictionary, and then write that to its own text file. When I run the program, I keep getting a TypeError with the save_the_dictionary function, since it's getting passed a dictionary instead of a string; however, I thought that my save_the_dictionary function changes each key-value pair into strings before they are written to the file, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any help with this would be greatly appreciate. Here is my code:

```
import os
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize


class Document:

    def tokenize(self, text):
        dictionary = {}
        for line in text:

            all_words = line.upper()

            words = word_tokenize(all_words)

            punctuation = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

            cleaned_words = []

            for word in words:
                if word not in punctuation:
                    cleaned_words.append(word)



            for word in cleaned_words:
                if word in dictionary:
                    dictionary[word] += 1
                else:
                    dictionary[word] = 1
        return dictionary        

    def save_the_dictionary(self, dictionary, filename): #This save function writes a new file, and turns each key and its corresponding value into strings and writes them into a text file-
        newfile = open(filename, "w")                    #, it also adds formatting by tabbing over after the key, writing the value, and then making a new line. Then it closes the file.
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            newfile.write(str(key) + "/t" + str(value) + "/n")
        file.close()

# The main idea of this method is that it first converts all the text to uppercase strips all of the formatting from the file that it is reading, then it splits the text into a list,-
# using both whitespace and the characters above as delimiters. After that, it goes through the entire list pulled from the text file, and sees if it is in the dictionary variable. If-
# it is in there, it adds 1 to the value associated with that key. If it is not found within the dictionary variable, it adds to as a key to the dictionary variable, and sets its value-
# to 1.

#The above document class will only be used within the actual vectorize function.

def vectorize(filepath):
    all_files = os.listdir(filepath)
    full_dictionary = {}

    for file in all_files:
        doc = Document()

        full_path = filepath + "\\" + file

        textfile = open(full_path, "r", encoding="utf8")

        text = textfile.read()

        compiled_dictionary = doc.tokenize(text)

        final_path = filepath + "\\final" + file

        doc.save_the_dictionary(final_path, compiled_dictionary)

        for line in text:

            all_words = line.upper()

            words = word_tokenize(all_words)

            punctuation = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

            cleaned_words = []

            for word in words:
                if word not in punctuation:
                    cleaned_words.append(word)



            for word in cleaned_words:
                if word in dictionary:
                    full_dictionary[word] += 1
                else:
                    full_dictionary[word] = 1
        Document().save_the_dictionary(filepath + "\\df.txt", full_dictionary)

vectorize("C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\*******\\*****\\*****\\Text files")
```

Comment: you're calling file.close() inside save_the_dictionary, should it be newfile ?

Comment: also in Document().save_the_dictionary(filepath + "\\df.txt", full_dictionary) you're giving the parameter in the reverse order you defined in the function  `save_the_dictionary(self, dictionary, filename)` , no ?

Comment: @Bernadostearnsreisen I fixed the arguments being passed. Thank you for that catch! When it comes to closing the file, I thought the method would create and write to  the new file, then close it.

Comment: does those changes solve your original problem?  better to be explicit in regards opening and closing files .  `with` is a nice syntax for that `with open(filename,"w") as newfile:`, it shows the context in which the file is open  and I don't see why you are using `file.close()`

Comment: @Bernadosternsreisen I see what you mean now! Thank you for that! I also now understand what you meant when you said "closing a new file". It's just being written, not actually opened and read. Thank you for taking the time to help with that!

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen Now I am getting an issue with it writing to the files. It isn't saving the dictionary. It is just saving /t and /n and random numbers.

Comment: if you update your code and tell about the error you're getting it would be helpful

Comment: I just solved the problem. The main issue were the backwards arguments, and a few other bugs (such as accidentally running the tokenize method twice within the vectorize for loop,  and also using the wrong direction of slashes within the save_the_dictionary function. Thank you for your help